# Error: Bad value expires for attribute http-equiv on element meta

Tags: html, html5

Buenos días, estoy pasando el [validador](https://validator.w3.org/) del W3C, y quisiera corregir este error.

Gcs

```
Error: Bad value expires for attribute http-equiv on element meta.

From line 18, column 1; to line 18, column 43

panish"/>↩<meta http-equiv="expires" content="never">↩<meta
```

Answer (score 1):

El valor `expires` no está permitido en HTML5 para la etiqueta `<meta>` y el atributo `http-equiv`, aquí puedes ver la especificación: https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-html5-20140617/document-metadata.html#pragma-directives

Los únicos valores permitidos son:

> 'content-language', 'content-type', 'default-style', 'refresh' y 'set-cookie'

---

La solución es enviar el campo en los encabezados, el cuál está definido aquí: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21

Un ejemplo es:

> Expires: Thu, 01 Dec 1994 16:00:00 GMT

Según la documentación para enviar "never" como fecha de expiración, **se debe enviar una fecha aproximadamente un año posterior al envio de la respuesta HTTP**, también se recomienda NO enviar fechas posteriores a un año en el futuro.

Comment: Hola, me sigue marcando el mismo error en el W3C mis etiquetas son estas: <meta name="language" content="spanish"/>
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Mon, 29 Aug 2017 17:06:13 GMT"/>

Comment: Hola, claro que te va a seguir mostrando el error, `expires` no es válido como valor en la etiqueta como dice la primera parte de la respuesta.

Comment: ¿Abria alguna forma de solucionarlo para que no marque error?

Comment: Disculpen la molestia, soy muy novato en la plataforma. No se como solucionar el error. Gcs

Answer (score 0):

Los atributos permitidos para `http-equiv` son:

`content-language`

`Content-Security-Policy`

`content-type`

`default-style`

`refresh`

`set-cookie`

Fuente:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta#attr-http-equiv

https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-meta-element.html#attr-meta-http-equiv

El caso que intentas usar `"expires"` es un caso especial y se [convierte](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/WD-html5-20140617/document-metadata.html#other-pragma-directives) en un header HTTP.

> Extensiones al set predefinido de directivas pueden, bajo ciertas circunstancias ser registradas en la página WHATWG Wiki PragmaExtensions.
>
> Dichas extensiones deben usar un nombre que es idéntico a una cabecera HTTP registrada en el Permanent Message Header Field Registry, y deben tener un comportamiento idéntico al descrito por dicha cabecera http.

De acuerdo al [spec](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21) debes usar un año posterior a la fecha del envío y siempre debe ser una fecha válida [RFC 1123](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1123.txt).

```
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Mon, 29 Aug 2017 17:06:13 GMT">
```

Comment: Me sigue marcando el mismo error mis etiquetas las tengo así. <meta name="language" content="spanish"/>
<meta http-equiv="expires" content="Mon, 29 Aug 2017 17:06:13 GMT"/>

Comment: @FernandoLopez Probé lo que me dices y al parecer el validador esta siendo demasiado estricto con el valor del atributo. Como te explico en la respuesta `expires` no es un valor reconocido sino un caso especial, de hecho en mi respuesta `Content-Security-Policy` solo es reconocido por mozilla y `set-cookie` y `content-language` son *no conformantes* por lo que me parece que no debes prestarle atención a la advertencia. De acuerdo al spec en el caso que la fecha sea inválida o 0 se trata como documento expirado.

Comment: @FernandoLopez Puedes comprobar esto en la documentación https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-meta-element.html#attr-meta-http-equiv en la sección **4.2.5.4 Other pragma directives**

Comment: Hola, ¿abria alguna forma de solucionarlo para que el W3C no lo vea como error?

Comment: @FernandoLopez. Si, la solución es no usarlo y en su lugar hacer que el server que sirve tu aplicación web escriba una cabecera HTTP `Expires` al enviar el documento o página HTML. Ese elemento `meta` como lo usas se hace con ese propósito, crear el equivalente de las cabeceras  HTTP. Lee la actualización de mi respuesta.